# a fourteen-day holiday vs fourteen days' holiday

Tags: word-usage, difference

I'm going on holiday on the 12th. I have to be back at work on the 26th.
So I've got
a) a fourteen-day holiday
b) fourteen days' holiday

I chose a), but the answer in the book is b).

Is "a fourteen-day holiday" acceptable here?

Comment: What book? Who wrote it?

Comment: Either would be correct.

Comment: This question is from "English Grammar in Use" by Raymond Murphy, Unit 81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be either - but if you are using the indefinite article it needs to be the first.

The choice is:

***I am going away for a fourteen-day holiday***

or

***I'm going away for fourteen days holiday***.

Each is grammatical, and it doesn't much matter which you use.

Comment: In Britain we would say **a fortnight's holiday**!

Comment: Yes, "a fortnight's holiday" and "two weeks' holiday" are other correct answers in the book.

Comment: @KateBunting Of course we would but we were not asked about that, only to choose between the two on offer.